# How can I find the distance from a particular latitude and longitude to surrounding area in km?

Tags: android, gps, apk

I am new to Android.  In my application, customer is at a location. I want to find agents near-by to that customer using his/her latitude and longitude.  How can I do this? customer is on one location & We want to search agents surronding that perticular customer.
I have latitude of customer and agents and based on I want to search agents(From customer's latitude longitude in surrounding area of 5 km. which agents are thare that i want to search).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do location based search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615403/how-to-do-location-based-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know agent's location, grab you current location [using built-in device gps receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android/1513569#1513569).

Then, calculate distance between your coordinates and the one of the agent using [distanceTo method of Location class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29)

Finally, found the small distance among all the distances you calculated.

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode

```
area = 100;
for a over allAgents
  if(Math.abs(a.x - customer.x) < area || Math.abs(a.y - customer.y) < area) 
    nearCustomerArray.add(a);
```

Comment: Note that this gives a rectangle of results. That may be sufficient approximation for a rectangular map, but might leave out some agents outside the square.

Comment: Yeah good point, for a circlebased location window you need to do basically the same but with some arc math stuff ;)